# How to check if item is in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I'm pretty new to javascript and I was wondering how to use the `localStorage` function in javascript. I want to know how to check if something is already in local storage, and trigger/not trigger an function if it is in localstorage/not in localstorage.
All help is appreaciated!

Comment: is this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/how-to-store-objects-in-html5-localstorage-sessionstorage

Comment: This should get you going, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. The MDN is a great resource when you are exploring new things in JavaScript. If you read that and are still stuck please feel free to post a new question.

Comment: @AdamH Thanks that looks like a good info website